# get property value from bindingList c#

Tags: c#, properties, bindinglist

I have binding list in `Class Restaurant`, which I need to call in my form `Form1` without using foreach to get properties. How could I access properties without foreach. Is that possible?

Here is my code:

```
   public static BindingList<MaterijaliGrid> GetMaterijali(DataGridView dataGridView1)
    {
        BindingList<MaterijaliGrid> materijali = new BindingList<MaterijaliGrid>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            //while (materijali.Count < 50)
            //{
            materijali.Add(new MaterijaliGrid
            {
                Cosort = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                Model = r.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                Type = r.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                Color = r.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                Aantal = r.Cells[4].Value.ToString(),

                Unit = r.Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
                Component = r.Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
                Aantal2 = r.Cells[7].Value.ToString(),
                Unitcomp = r.Cells[8].Value.ToString(),
                Opis = r.Cells[9].Value.ToString(),
                Kleur = r.Cells[10].Value.ToString(),
                Soort = r.Cells[11].Value.ToString(),
                Price = r.Cells[12].Value.ToString(),
                Price1 = r.Cells[13].Value.ToString(),
                Price2 = r.Cells[14].Value.ToString(),
                // Oznaka = "MTK"
            });
        }
        //}
        return materijali;
    }
```

Comment: This code screams: "NullReferenceException"

Comment: @Yosi becouse values are setted from excel file

Comment: And why don't you want to use foreach? It exists for a reason.

Comment: @steve because of homework ?!

Comment: I need for selected cell in dataGridView to get values only for that selected property not to go through all

Comment: @Yosi Yes its homework

Comment: You can extract it from anywhere, still in a safe way. don't assume `r.Cells[14]` is not null, don't assume `r.Cells[14].Value` is not null.

Comment: @Yosi How do you mean, could you write how can i get that row from another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want much cleaner code I would suggest that you should bind your object into your DataGridView. Then, convertion would be easy. Something like this:

```
// Replace list of person with your MaterijaliGrid object
var list = new List<Person>();
list.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Robert", Initial = "Santos", LastName = "Lee" });
list.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Robert1", Initial = "Santos1", LastName = "Lee1" });
list.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Robert2", Initial = "Santos2", LastName = "Lee2" });
list.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Robert3", Initial = "Santos3", LastName = "Lee3" });

// You can hide row header if don't want it.  
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;    
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;            
dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Now you can easily cast it like this:

```
// Replace List and BindingList of person with your MaterijaliGrid object
var list = new List<Person>();
list.AddRange(dataGridView1.Rows
                           .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem as Person));

var bindingList = new BindingList<Person>(list);
```

Person class :

```
public class Person 
{
   // In case you don't want to display class property with there original names
   // you can annotate the property with DisplayName

   [DisplayName("First Name")]
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string Initial {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Sample Output :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> without using foreach to get properties

There are multiple ways to enumerate any data collection in C# such as the [do](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx), [for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx), [foreach in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx), and the [while](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx) which are all language specific.

Also since .Net 3.5 (~roughly since 2008) there are extensions added which handle list processing in C# that is [Language-Integrated Query (LINQ)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) which standard, easily-learned patterns for *querying* and updating data. The term *querying* is the ability to write an expression that retrieves data from a data source regardless of whether that source is local (to the code such as in an array or a list) or in from a database.

See [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) which is a fine introcution to Linq.